# Wiring a Heater, Vent Fan, Light for bathroom

Tags: electrical, wiring

So I am trying to get my new bathroom vent/light/heater installed. I have been up and down in my attic so many times and have had one of the functions working each time, but never all three. I got the heater to turn on and off. I got the light to turn on and off. I got the vent to run, but it would run no matter like there was no switch. I am thoroughly confused at this point. [image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the switch box, and post the install instructions as well?

Comment: Can you replace the cable between switch box and fan? This whole deal would be 10 times easier if you were using /4 cable instead of /2 and /3 cable.   Also it would be more legal.

Comment: Yes, where does power come into this for that matter?

Comment: Will post a picture of the switch tonight. I guess I could run a new wire up there but that is how it was originally setup so I am trying to use them.  It is on its own circuit and the power comes from the breaker.

Comment: Can't tell for sure without model # to check but you have a white == neutral on the switch which probably shouldn't be there. Except for Smart switches normally just black hot on one side and the colored switched hots on the other.

Comment: I think with how I have it wired at the unit I can take the white out at the switch and tie it in with the other whites and then put the other black in where the white was and that should complete the circuit correctly?

Comment: They are using the 3 colors in the /3 cable as the 3 switched hots to the fan/light/heater.   They are using the neutral in the /2 cable.  This is an illegal configuration, you can't send power up one cable and back down another: the current return for each device must be back in the same cable so the currents and magnetic fields in each wire cancel each other out.   otherwise you get heating on any nail or strap between the cables (a fair bit due to the high current of the heater) and the cables vibrate due to magnetism, which will fatigue them, causing arcing and fire.

Comment: Well I guess this is what happens back in 1998 ha.  Thank the lord there hasn't been any kind of fire yet, but makes me nervous about how the rest of the house is wired.  I am going to fix tonight, thankfully I won't have to get back up in the attic.  That would also explain why I could never get the configuration right at the unit.  Should have looked at the switch earlier.  Live and learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to tell from the pictures what you currently have. But here is (roughly) what you need.

*Updating based on newly posted installation diagram*

#### Assumptions

- Installing 3 switches in one box Note: I do **not** know much about how much you can stuff in a box. There are some experts here who can speak to that - when I did this in my own house, my electrician dealt with those details (and many more). I got something like this [Decora 15 Amp 3-Rocker Switch](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Decora-15-Amp-3-Rocker-Combination-Switch-White-R62-01755-0WS/100356847) which can fit in a single gang box, but be warned that a single gang box is likely not big enough for all these wires (code or practically speaking).
- Everything on one circuit - i.e., a single 15A or 20A circuit as appropriate based on the requirements of the fan/light/heater - primarily the heater is the determining factor

#### In the switch box:

- Cable 1: From the main panel: Black (hot), white (neutral), ground. Hot goes to all three switches. Neutral will connect to neutral from all three devices.
- Cables 2 & 3: To the devices: Typically **2** cables. One black/white/ground (this is the /2 - 2 wires + ground), one black/red/white/ground (this is the /3 - 3 wires + ground). (Technically this could be done with one bigger cable or with 3 black/white/ground cables or with a bunch of individual wires in conduit, but it looks like you have the typical 2 cables already, so that's good).
- Connect all the neutral (white) wires together with a wire nut.
- If your switches have three **pairs** of screws then connect three short black wires (same size, easiest to just strip a section of Romex and chop off 3 pieces of black wire) together with the black wire from the panel with a wire nut and connect each to one screw. If your switch has a **common** hot then you connect the hot from the panel directly to it.
- Connect each **colored** wire from the cables 2 & 3 to a switch. Two switches get black, one gets red - these are all *switched hots*.
- All grounds are connected together.

**No white wires to the switch unless it is a smart switch that uses neutral**

**If your switch has backstab connections and screws always use the screws.**

#### At the fan:

- Connect the neutrals for the light & fan (whites that are paired with the blue & black wires) to the white in the /3 cable.
- Connect the neutral for the heat (white that is paired with the red wire) to the white in the /2 cable.
- Connect the black (fan) wire to the black wire in the /3 cable.
- Connect the blue (light) wire to the red wire in the /3 cable.
- Connect the red (heat) wire to the black wire in the /2 cable.
- Connect all grounds together (as always)

Color-coding: Because the heat uses a lot more power than the light & fan, it gets the /2 cable. Harper recommends (and it is a good idea) marking both ends of the /2 black --> **red** and both ends of the /3 red --> **blue**. That will make all the wire colors match, which will help with any future troubleshooting. **However**, you must make sure that the whites go to the correct (/2 for heat, /3 for fan & light) whites - neutrals & hots must be matched together.

That should leave you with nothing extra hanging out. And you should have each switch operating a separate function in the fan/light/heater.

You also need to vent the fan properly. I had my electrician do that too (not a fun job in my attic). You definitely do **NOT** want the fan venting into the open area of your attic. If you had another fan before then you may be able to reuse the ductwork and the hole in the roof. If not, that may be the hardest part of the job.

Comment: So the only thing I don't have connected the way you mentioned is I don't have all the whites (three from unit and two from switch) connected with a nut. I have the heater white connected to one white and then the light and vent white connected to the other.  Is this what is causing the issue maybe? I have the switch you referenced above already installed. I am going to check the switch box tomorrow.

Comment: I got part wrong - each cable neutral gets connected to the neutral(s) of the matching colored wires - that is the white with black/red connects to neutrals of the devices that have their colored wires connected to that black and red. It sounds like you got that part right.

Comment: So if that is the case then my issue is probably in the switch. I'll take a look tomorrow. What would be the issue in the switch that is causing the fan to just run no matter and none of the switches to work?

Comment: Thank you for the update and edit above.  How you just said is exactly how I have it set up now and the vent fan runs without any switch turned on and when you try to turn anything on nothing happens.  I figure the problem must be in the switch then, does that sound like it could be the case?  If the switch is just letting the power flow straight through.  I will check tonight to make sure it is set up correctly.

Comment: Do you have **three** switches? Each one should have 2 screws. The pigtailed black hot wires go to one screw on each switch. The colored cables from the /2 and /3 each go to one screw on one switch. To troubleshoot, disconnect **ALL** wires from the switches. Connect one hot black to one switch. Connect one colored /2 or /3 to the other screw of that same switch. (Cap everything else with wire nuts before turning the breaker back on). See if it works. Repeat for each of the other switches.

Comment: Um so I found out that the wiring is actually on two different circuits. A line comes in that is associated with my back room wall. I think I blew the fuse for the heater when I switched it on. Ugh.

Comment: I fixed it! And it works!!! So happy.

Comment: So I suspect in the end it was NOT actually two different circuits, and just that you had something "backwards", right?

Comment: I think it was the line to the bedroom in case someone wanted to put a switch on wall right the plugs on the back wall. I got them tied back together and got the new triple switch hooked up and it works like a charm. So happy.

Answer (score 1):

You need some colored electrical tape.

On the /2 cable, on both ends of the cable, mark the black wire with red tape.

On the /3 cable, on both ends of the cable, mark the red wire with blue tape.

---

In the heater, attach the /2 cable first.  Red goes to red (heater hot) and white goes to *the heater's white wire* which should not be connected to the fan or light's white wire.

In the heater, second, attach the /3 cable to the remaining wires, super simple, same color to same color.

---

Down in the 3-switch switch box, all the grounds from all cables go together.  All the neutrals (whites) go together.

Now one of the cables in the switch box is the supply.  That one's hot wire needs to be split 3 ways, e.g. By being wire-nutted to 3 **pigtails**.   You have 3 switches with 2 (non-green) screws each.  Each pigtail goes to a different switch, and attaches to one of the screws.

Still unattached are the black, red and blue coming from the fan. 2 of them have been relabeled with tape, use the tape color not the native wire color.  Each switch still has a remaining screw unused.  That is where those 3 wires go; one per switch.

And you're done.

Comment: Well the red is in the /3 wire with another black and then there is a black in the /2 wire line.

Comment: What Harper is saying (and I agree) is to **mark** the black wire in the /2 **red** - and from that point on all references to "the red wire" refer to that (formerly black) wire. Similarly, **mark** the red wire in the /3 **blue** - and from that point on all references to "the blue wire" refer to that (formerly red) wire.

Comment: The red won't be in the /3 wire after you mark it blue.  Colors in cables are not there to help you, they are there as a necessity of cable manufacture. You can re-mark them *to suit your own purposes*, and it'll make your life easier if you do, and make it clearer next time you are in there.  The one in the /2 **cable** needs to be red because that /2 needs to power the heater, and red is the color the manufacturer selected for heat.  Do it that way, the colors match and it's easy mode.  Don't underestimate the value of simplicity when dealing with an octopus like this.

Comment: That makes sense and I believe that is how I have it connected at the moment.  For some reason I think the problem might be in the switch.  I am going to check and make sure the switch layout is correct tonight and it may just be time to replace the switch.

Comment: It almost looks like they hooked up a white as a hot wire instead going up to the unit.